# Redirect user to a personal page based on Username

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In Wordpress, how can I redirect a user to his specific personal page automatically after login? The page is based on his Username ID: sitename.com/username (registered in Users).

I want each user be redirect to a different page (his page), but the URL will have the same structure, like above (/username).

I'm not using WooCommerce. I'm not looking for redirect by role.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use action on form for example:

```
<form action="sitename.com/username/<?php echo $user_registred_from_users; ?>" </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme functions.php

If you want redirect by current user role:

```
function redirect_after_login() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  switch($user->roles[0])
  {
    case 'administrator': $redirect = 'wp-admin'; break;
    case 'subscriber': $redirect = '/custom-url'; break;
  }
  return $redirect;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_after_login');
```

If you want redirect by current user id:

```
function redirect_after_login() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  switch($user_id)
  {
    case 1: $redirect = 'wp-admin'; break;
    case 2: $redirect = '/custom-url'; break;
  }
  return $redirect;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_after_login');
```